# my site is not showing in google search why?

Tags: http, web, google-search

I've read the questions and searched. My URL is: http://website.com
I recently created a website for one of our client, and added content and images are setup. I've verified the site with google webmasters, added analytics to the site.

The issue that I am experiencing is that I am searching for the keyword "" and our domain "http://website.com" is not showing up at all. Even if I type as "site:website.com" the domain doesn't show up.

I would appreciate if some one could assist me, if am doing anything wrong?

**GOT IT:**

Thanks for all who tried to assist me...

Comment: Did you add it to google search directory? Look here http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/website-owner/

Comment: yes i did.. Mr.Maxzeroedge

Comment: Did you try to get your website crawled by the webmaster? You may need to upload your sitemap for that.

Comment: Have you tried [asking Google to crawl](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?rd=1) your website?

Comment: yes i have tried both.. sitemap and recrawled.. but still no solution

Answer (score 2):

Google does not add your site immediately to their search index. Even if Google already crawled your site it can take more than a day until it is added to the public available search index.

Try it again in 24-48hours and contact google if it still does not show up.

Comment: may be you are right... just yesterday, i added my site to google. i will wait and see..

Comment: got to admit it's weird. you are in bing search index at least. http://www.bing.com/search?q=gamekut.com